# How do I recover my Minecraft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

From 2013-2015, I had an old Minecraft account that I migrated on a computer I don't have anymore using an email that I don't remember. I sort of forgot about it until pretty recently, where I now struggle in trying to get it back.

I checked and made sure that my account has not been compromised and I've tried every method that I could, from trial and error to sending password change requests to every email I can remember. I can't get into the account but I'm opposed to buying it again. I've even looked up hacking programs among other things to no avail because they're randomized and meant for attacking random accounts. Anything I could do would be appreciated.

Note: As I do not remember the email, I do not have the transaction ID.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you in this case.

Comment: Try sending an email to Mojang, mentioning your username, and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the username? If it's old enough, you won't have a mojang account for it and may be able to send a password using that. If not, there is no way to get back to your account.